# Android Dev: Navigation View vs App Bar

Tags: java, android, toolbar, navigationview, appbar

I'm new to Android development. I get that a NavigationView is an AppBar (i think). What makes these two different? I want to create a custom "appbar/toolbar" with a centered logo and menu/settings button in the top right corner (instead of the standard left) which reveals a drawer.

I was going to ditch the built in appbar/toolbar all together and just create my own somehow and include button overlay which displays a drawer.

What would you do? Navigation view, app bar, or custom toolbar from scratch? I don't know what the standard is or what is acceptable. What is the difference between a navigationview and appbar.  Thank you.

edit: I'm slowing realizing that an appbar is one feature within a navigation view, among others like a drawer layout, menu items etc... i think.

Comment: Do you want the drawer that slides out and almost covers the activity and greys out the background, or like a simple overflow menu coming off of a top bar?

Comment: The drawer that slides out and covers the activity.

Comment: Excellent beginner question.  This is one of the many UI/UX issues that seem redundant and therefore confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. NavigationView**
By using NavigationView, we can bind the menu directly with NavigationView. This is the benefit of the NavigationView. No need to create ListView and adapter with navigation drawer. By default we can get selector of item click. With menu we can change the color of icon of selected menu.
For more details : 
1.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html

2. http://www.technotalkative.com/part-4-playing-with-navigationview/

**2. AppBar**
Appbar is for toolbar with scrolling effect. We can easily give the material design effect. 
For more details : 
1.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html